# Slow Query when using multiple between

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, between, business-objects

I'm including a new option on an already working query/report on business objects.
Basically it already gets the records that were created from the first of last month and today dates.

I want to add the records from the previous year's same dates (last month and previous year and today previous year).

When I introduced the OR operator to include a new between date the report that usually takes 2 minutes, won't run in less than 30 minutes.

This Works great:

```
Select
 value1
 creation
From
 Table
Where
 creation  BETWEEN  trunc((trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1),'mm') AND trunc(sysdate)
```

This takes more than 30 min:

```
Select
 value1
 creation
From
 Table
Where
 (creation  BETWEEN  add_months(trunc((trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1),'mm'),-12) AND add_months(trunc(sysdate),-12)
  OR   creation  BETWEEN  trunc((trunc(sysdate,'mm')-1),'mm') AND trunc(sysdate))
```

Comment: Not relevant, but your outer `trunc()` calls aren't doing anything. Have you looked at the execution plans? At a guess the `or` is leading the optimiser to a full scan of the table or index. How long does it take with just the year-ago dates, and how selective are those two date ranges?

Comment: Can you include the two query plans?  My blind guess would be to try writing it as a `UNION ALL` of two queries rather than an `OR`.

Comment: Did you try same query with comparison operators (>= or <=)? Did you see any difference?

Comment: @hudossan . . . That is interesting.  Oracle supports skip-scans on indexes, so it should work for the `or` version.  You can always use `union all` instead.

Comment: @AlexPoole Only a couple of minutes, using only this year or using only the year-ago querys. The problem is when I join the two conditions on the "OR".

Comment: @JustinCave its the same query plan / same report, I just didn't want to create a query for this year and another query for last year since it uses the exact same fields/query.

Comment: How can it be the same query plan?  Surely at least the access/ filter conditions are different.  What is the query plan?  We can guess at possible query plans that might cause performance issues but it's a lot easier if we can see the actual plan.

Comment: @PavanChandaka How so? If I use them separately it works just fine, either using "between" or ">=" operators.

Comment: @JustinCave Sorry I've misunderstood your question. I don't have the query plan. I create reports using business Objects, and then I update the SQL as needed, so it only executes the query and give me the results.

Comment: Can you get the query plan (your DBA should be able to help if you don't have permission)?  Without knowing the plan, it is very, very difficult to say anything certain.

Comment: @JustinCave I'll try to get that.

Comment: It worked with the union all perfectly, Thank's for the sugestion JustinCave & GordonLinoff.